# Mysql: selecting relative to second table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables:

entities:

```
id
```

statuses:

```
id
entity_id
status
```

Each entity can have many statuses and i need to select only the entities that have 'paid' status and do not have 'canceled' status. How do i do a proper join for that?

Example:

```
entities: id 7
entities: id 8
entities: id 9
entities: id 10
statuses: id 1, entity_id 7, status 'paid'
statuses: id 2, entity_id 7, status 'canceled'
statuses: id 3, entity_id 8, status 'paid'
statuses: id 4, entity_id 10, status 'onhold'
statuses: id 5, entity_id 8, status 'whatever'
```

Only entiry with the id of `8` will be selected once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM 
entities as e INNER JOIN statuses as spaid 
           ON e.id = spaid.entity_id and spaid.status = 'paid'
    LEFT JOIN statuses as scanceled 
           ON e.id = scanceled.entity_id and scanceled.status = 'canceled'
WHERE scanceled.id IS NULL
```

The first join takes entities that have a 'paid' status.

The second join would add the second status for entities that have a 'canceled' status, or NULL for entities that do not have a canceled status

The where clause then filters the entries, taking only the rows that have NULL as the 'canceled' status.

Comment: It seems to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. We group up the statuses by entity ID and filter them after grouping to only those that have a MIN and MAX of paid. Entity 7 will have a MIN of "canceled" and a MAX of "paid" so it is excluded.

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM 
entities e
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT entity_id FROM statuses s 
  GROUP BY entity_id
  HAVING 
    MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'canceled' THEN status ELSE 'not canceled' END) = 'not canceled' AND 
    MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'paid' then 'paid' ELSE 'not paid' END) = 'paid'
) a
ON 
  a.entity_id = e.id
```

A bit more on MIN and MAX, as per your comment:

You say things can be many statuses but really we are only interested in PAID things, and then we are only interested in those PAID things if they have never had a CANCELED. What we do, then with the statuses is:

- Turn everything other than "canceled" into "not canceled"
- Turn everything other than "paid" into "not paid"
- Link row entries up and look for pairings of "paid"/"not canceled"

To see what I mean, look at:

```
SELECT 
  entity_id,
  CASE WHEN status = 'paid' then 'paid' ELSE 'not paid' END as is_paid,
  CASE WHEN status = 'canceled' THEN status ELSE 'not canceled' END as is_cancelled
FROM
  status
```

Now take a look at:

```
SELECT 
  entity_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'paid' then 'paid' ELSE 'other' END) as is_paid,
  MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'canceled' THEN status ELSE 'not canceled' END) as is_cancelled
FROM
  status
GROUP BY
  entity_id
```

This is a "pivot" operation; it conceptually turns rows into columns. The multiple rows for item 7 become a single row with multiple columns. The min and max work out because, alphabetically, "paid" is after "not paid", and "canceled" is before "

This is how we look for the "paid"/"not canceled" pairing. At this point we could say this:

```
SELECT * FROM entities INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    entity_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'paid' then 'paid' ELSE 'other' END) as is_paid,
    MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'canceled' THEN status ELSE 'not canceled' END) as is_cancelled
  FROM
    status
  GROUP BY
    entity_id
) finder
ON 
  entities.id = finder.entity_ID
WHERE
  finder.is_paid = 'paid' and finder.is_canceled = 'not canceled'
```

It's just a bit shorter to do this filtering earlier using HAVING rather than later using WHERE

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain this having min and max?

Comment: Sorry. This will select only entities which have paid statuses and no other status. But entity can have multiple statuses. All i care is paid is present and canceled is not present. I updated  my initial question by adding another example row.

Comment: Amended the answer